# PHP escape user input for filename

Tags: php

I have a form where users can upload files, and I'd like to name the file something along the lines of `[id]_[lastname]_[firstname].pdf`. The name is entered by the user, and I'm afraid of them entering something with a slash in it. Otherwise, something like `$path = $dir.$filename` could result in `$path = 'uploads/2_smith_john/hahaimajerk.pdf'` if the firstname is `john/hahaimajerk`.

I don't really want to force users to restrict their names to anything; I don't mind changing their names a little in the file name as long as I can tell the original name. What characters do I need to escape, or is there some other way to do this? Or...do I just use `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: As Alex N. says, escapeshellarg is what you're looking for, but I would strongly consider assigning known to be safe filenames and mapping them through you database, potentially to user-friendly filenames.

Comment: worse: imagine a firstname of "/../../../etc/passwd"

Comment: Generally speaking "." and ".." are important to consider as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` won't escape slashes. Even `escapeshellarg` won't do it. You will have to use `str_replace`:

```
$path = str_replace('/', '_', $path);
```

Comment: I was worried there were other symbols that could be dangerous - hopefully / is the only issue.

Comment: `escapeshellarg` and such is only useful when sending shell commands (using shell_exec, exec and such), to ensure that other operators (like `;`, `&&` or backticks) are escaped, in order to prevent shell command injection (similar to SQL injection, but in a shell, and WAY more harmful). PHP's filesystem functions (`fopen`, `file_put_contents` and such) don't have to escape filenames. Worst case scenario in your situation (i.e.: without str_replace), PHP will fail to write the file with a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: The OS might also disallow certain characters within filenames (for instance, Windows does not allow the colon `:`, as well as various other characters), which is a problem that this answer does not solve.  If you're not sure what server environment your code will run on, Tommy Lacroix's answer is far superior.

Answer (score 85):

I usually use regular expressions for this. And instead of removing certain specific characters (like slashes, dots, etc), I prefer to only allow certain characters (like alphanumeric)

For instance, this will replace any character that is not a letter, a number, a dash or an underscore by an underscore:

```
$escaped = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_\-]/', '_', $raw);
```

The backslash before the dash is to escape the dash in the regular expression, as dashes are otherwise used to specify character ranges (such as A-Z).

Comment: dash at the end (or start) are not considered as a range indicator

Comment: Using this way, dot between file name and file extension will be escaped too.

Comment: @SAMPro true, but it is a file NAME we are talking about, you should always make your own extension after checking MIME-TYPE some reliable way (e.g. [Fileinfo module](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php))

Comment: /[^\w-]/ is enough !

Answer (score 3):

The only "unsafe" character in a filename is `/` - so you can easily avoid problems by using `str_replace("/","",$filename)`

Comment: "." and ".." can cause trouble too.

Comment: `.` and `..` are harmless without the `/`.

Comment: ...but are still reserved names and IMO ought to be considered.

Comment: `.` can be harmful if it's your whole filename. For example, `rmdir(realpath($pathToWeb . '../uploads/' . $userInput))` or some similar situation

Comment: You should thus use `$filename = preg_replace('((^\.)|\/|(\.$))', '_', $filename)` -- which escapes *any* slash and every dot at the start or end.