# reading in a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've downloaded files from my svn that are now stored on a document on my local disk. Most of these files are php files. How can I read in documents (that aren't "txt") which are located on my local disk and open them on a website that uses php. So so far this is what I have,

```
index.php

    $(function() {
        $('#getData').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "endPoint.php",
                data : { field2_name : $('#userInput2').val() },
                beforeSend: function(){
                }
                , complete: function(){
                }
                , success: function(html){
                    //this will add the new comment to the `comment_part` div
                    $("#displayParse").html(html);
                    //$('[name=field1_name]').val('');
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>


<form id="comment_form" action="endPoint.php" method="GET">
    Enter the file you would like to view:
    <input type="text" class="text_cmt" name="field2_name" id="userInput2"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id = "getData"/>
    <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='0'/>
</form>

<div id="displayParse">
</div>
```

endPoint.php

```
<?php

$filePath = $_GET["field2_name"];
$url = "cs242_final/home/" . $filePath;

$file = fopen($url, "r");
fread($file,filesize($url));

echo '<div class="comment">' . $file . '</div>';


?>
```

basically the user inputs a file they want to open, and the files are located on my local disk. Not sure where I'm going wrong as the file contents are not being printed out. Also I am running my code on localhost using MAMP. The IDE I'm using is phpstorm. I'm not sure if my documents need to be loaded onto phpstorm in order to access them

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the value of `fread($file,filesize($url));` to anything. Try:

```
$contents = fread($file,filesize($url));
echo '<div class="comment">' . $contents . '</div>';
```

Also if this is used in a production environment make sure you [properly escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289905/php-escape-user-input-for-filename) the user input for the file name or bad things could happen.

Comment: it's printing out empty :/ so it's not recognizing the contents of the file. The files I have are on my local disk, does that make a difference?

Comment: That's a mysql error and has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: ?? i mean the code i put up is what I have I don't know why I'd have a mysql error?

Comment: Well you must have more code than what you listed here because that comes from mysql.

Comment: BTW that's not an error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417308/getting-resource-id-3-error-in-mysql